# Как заменять/удалять ссылки в сообщении aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу сделать функцию замены ссылок в сообщении, разобрался как можно создавать ссылки через код, но никак не могу разобраться с тем как можно заменять одну ссылку на другую в сообщении пользователя.

Comment: Что значит `заменить ссылку`?

Comment: Изменить одну ссылку на другую

Comment: Приведите пример до и после.

Comment: Пример:  Какой-то текст https://web.telegram.org/ после замены: Какой-то текст https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457342/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-aiogram?noredirect=1#comment2605405_1457342

Comment: Короче это невозможно, так как придётся редактировать сообщения юзера, а телеграм скажете тебе - низя.

Comment: Но если ты хочешь просто удалить сообщение то можно

Comment: А если сделать что бы пользователь отправлял сообщение, а бот отправлял сообщение уже с замененными ссылки

Comment: Но это будет делать конкретно бот, юзерское сообщение не изменится

Comment: В этом и заключался вопрос, просто я изначально не правильно изьяснил мысль

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот хендлер который ловит ссылки, удаляет их и отправляет от имени бота такое же сообщение с измененными ссылками.

PS. Немного соврал. Не такие же. Если было фото/видео/аудио/документ то он просто игнорит этот факт и отправляет обычное сообщение.
Мне немного лень с этим париться ибо фиксится простыми условиями типа `if message.photo: await answer_photo(...)` и тд

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter
from aiogram.types import MessageEntityType
from aiogram.utils.markdown import link

import config # <- в нем лежит мой токен, игнорируй

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN) # <- делай как у тебя
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


# делаем фильтр
class FilterLinks(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, message: types.Message):
        if msg_entities := (message.entities or message.caption_entities):
            entities = []
            for entitie in msg_entities:
                if entitie.type in [MessageEntityType.URL, MessageEntityType.TEXT_LINK]:
                    entities.append(entitie)
            # этот словарь идет в хендлер ниже
            return {"entities": entities} if entities else False

# делаем хендлер с нашим фильтром + добавляем несколько типов,
# они будут срабатывать для message.caption_entities
@dp.message_handler(FilterLinks(), content_types=['text', 'photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
async def bot_message(message: types.Message, entities: dict):
    new_message = message.text or message.caption
    for entitie in entities:
        new_link = "www.google.com"
        prev_ = new_message[:entitie.offset]
        next_ = new_message[entitie.offset + entitie.length:]
        if entitie.type == MessageEntityType.TEXT_LINK:
            new_link = link(new_message[entitie.offset:entitie.offset + entitie.length], new_link)
        new_message = f"{prev_}{new_link}{next_}"

    await message.delete()
    await message.answer(new_message, parse_mode="Markdown")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```