# Как научить телеграм бота банить нового юзера в чате если в его первом сообщении есть спам-ссылка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Сообственно вопрос в заголовке
пока есть такой код, который просто удаляет сообщения со ссылкой, но так как ссылки в чате нужны, появилась идею бороться со спамом следующим образом: а именно банить только новых юзеров в чьём первом сообщении присутствует какая либо ссылка, т.к. спамер обычно сразу отправляет рекламы чего-либо не заморачиваясь что-то писать. вопрос как изменить код в соответствии с тз?

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])  # Зашел
async def on_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=["left_chat_member"])  # Вышел
async def on_user_exit(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
    
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
async def filter_message(message: types.Message):
    if ".ru" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".org" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".com" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".uk" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".net" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".info" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "https" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "http" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "www" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "xyz" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".cite" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "@" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif ".to" in message.text:
        await message.delete()

    elif "t.me" in message.text:
        await message.delete()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp,  skip_updates=False)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменять/удалять ссылки в сообщении aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457342/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-aiogram)

Comment: А как понять что сообщение первое, ну сделайте какую-то пометку в бд и после сверяйтесь ибо телеграм не дает такого понятия как первое сообщение (разве что старт)